# Message deleted automatically RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

I have used RabbitMQ for storing messages. I noticed that messages are deleted when application restart.

I have producer and consumer in same application.

Please find producer and consumer as below. I have used durable queue as well as durable message.

So if there is only one consumer of queue and it's not consume currently then queue messages are deleted. Is it so ?

**Producer:**

```
public static void PublishMessage(RequestDto message, string queueName)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = Config.RabbitMqHostName, Port = Config.RabbitMqPortNumber };

        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);

                var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                properties.SetPersistent(true);
               // properties.DeliveryMode = 2; I have used this too.

                string serializesMessage = Utility.SerializeSoapObject(message);

                var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializesMessage);

                channel.BasicPublish("", queueName, properties , messageBytes);

                Log.Info("Record added into queue : \nMessage: " + serializesMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Consumer:**

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = Config.RabbitMqHostName, Port = Config.RabbitMqPortNumber };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.QueueDeclare(Config.RabbitMqQueueName, true, false, false, null);

                    var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    channel.BasicConsume(Config.RabbitMqQueueName, true, consumer);

                    while (DoProcessMessage())
                    {
                          try
                            {
                                List<RequestDto> messages = GetMessagesInBatch(consumer);

                                if (messages.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    ProcessMessageInParallel(messages);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Producer.FillRequestMessages();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception exception)
                            {
                                Log.Error("StartConsumer - Failed to process message from RabbitMq Error: " + exception.Message, exception);
                            }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception.Message, exception);
        }

    private bool DoProcessMessage()
    {
        return Config.MaxRequestPerDayCount > 1000;
    }
```

If anyone can help.

Comment: Can you confirm via RabbitMQ management panel that queue is persistent and message in it has delivery_mode=2? Are there by change any logic that removes or purge queue on app shutdown or start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be passing `noAck = true` to the basicConsume function:
 https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v1.7.0/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-1.7.0/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#basicConsume(java.lang.String, boolean, com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer)

In no ack mode, RabbitMQ will send the messages to the consumer and immediately delete it from the queue.